# »No sé español« vs »No hablo español«

Tags: definiciones

What's the difference between *no sé español* and *no hablo español*? It seems to be the case that people don't say the former, however we can say "I don't know Spanish" in English. Moreover it appears that it's okay to say *no sé español bien*, so why is it strange to say *no sé español*? What's meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing strange.
I'd say it's a matter of preference.

*no sé español* or *no hablo español* are widely used in order for you to state that you don't have Spanish knowledge.

Similarly, in my country, many people often say *no sé inglés* or *no hablo inglés*.

A far-fetched example could be something like *sé español, pero no lo hablo*, this implies that the speaker has knowledge about Spanish language but it doesn't necessarily imply that this person has the other main abilities. For instance, *no hablo español, pero puedo leerlo.*

In the case *no sé español*, yields the possibility that the speaker won't be able to use anything about the Spanish language.